# How to rotate 180 degrees a report in Jasper Reports?

Tags: rotation, jasper-reports, orientation

For practical concerns I need to print a report 180 degree rotated (upside-down). Is there any way in jasper report to do that? Doing it in ireport or programmatically at runing time is the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to rotate text/paragraph in jasper report to left, right and upside down.[Please have a look in the doc.](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/rotation/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to rotate every objet in the report and mantain to diferent reports. There is an orientation atribute at report level but it only admits Landscape or Portrait